# what does x[:t:] do in python? <RNN>

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I've been studying RNN for language model and found its code with Tensorflow in a book.
But I really don't understand what `x[:t:]` does in the code below.....
I am a beginner for machine learning, if anybody knows, plz give me a clue.

=======code========

```
def inference(x, n_batch, maxlen=None, n_hidden=None, n_out=None):
    def weight_variable(shape):
        initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.01)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    def bias_variable(shape):
        initial = tf.zeros(shape, dtype=tf.float32)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(n_hidden)
    initial_state = cell.zero_state(n_batch, tf.float32)

    state = initial_state
    outputs = []
    with tf.variable_scope('RNN'):
        for t in range(maxlen):
            if t > 0:
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            (cell_output, state) = cell(x[:, t, :], state)
            outputs.append(cell_output)

    output = outputs[-1]

    V = weight_variable([n_hidden, n_out])
    c = bias_variable([n_out])
    y = tf.matmul(output, V) + c

    return y
```

Comment: x[:t:] or x[:, t, :]?

Comment: This depends entirely on the type of `x`, which you did not provide.

Comment: @timgeb -- Based on the tags, I'd be willing to bet that it's almost certainly a tensorflow tensor (which behaves a lot like a numpy array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `x` is a 3D-matrix. In that case, `[:,t,:]` extracts a 2-D matrix as the `t`th slice of the cube, in the XZ plane.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> x
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
>>> x[:,1,:]
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23]])
```

`:` means that the axis is left untouched. `[:,:,:]` would return the whole matrix, `[1,:,:]` would extract the second slice along the first axis:

```
>>> x[1,:,:]
array([[ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

Here's the corresponding [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing).